# Question about highlighted part of this text

Tags: sentence-meaning

> NEW YORK — Perry Ellis is not a brand that makes men nervous or causes them to titter. Even if a work-a-day guy doesn’t wear Perry Ellis clothes, he probably recognizes the name from those times he has wandered through a department store looking to stock up on dress shirts. Perry Ellis is not niche; it is mass. And its creative director, Michael Maccari designed a spring 2016 collection that was welcoming to a wide swath of men. Board shorts, crewneck sweaters, lean — but not tight — suits. Rich colors but nothing too psychedelic.
>
> Much of what Maccari  put on the runway might actually have been better appreciated in a more intimate setting where audience members are able to put their hands on the fabric, see the details up close. But putting Perry Ellis on the runway during the inaugural season of New York Fashion Week: **Men’s, served a larger purpose** . It sent a message: This, too, is fashion. And there’s nothing to fear.

1. Could you explain in simple English that why the writer wrote Men's ? Men's what?
2. When saying **it served a largere purpose** , what does he mean by saying **to serve** ?

Comment: What is the source of your example? "New York Fashion Week: Men’s" should have been accentuated somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Fashion shows typically all take place during a fairly short period, and define "fashion" for the next year.

Of course, originally fashion shows only featured women's fashions, but this has changed.

1) This year, the Council of Fashion Designers of America (CFDA) decided to launch a formal week of fashion shows for men's ware http://cfda.com/programs/new-york-mens-week and called it **New York Fashion Week: Men's**

2) When an action is performed with intent, the action is said to serve a purpose. In this case, including Ellis fashions not only served the purpose of displaying the fashions, it also served a larger purpose: defining (or at least asserting from a position of power) fashion as including these sorts of designs.